# Spring login x,y parameters

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to build login for Restful web services with spring for already existing applicaiton.
It uses spring security. I dont seem to be able to login. I noticed that form login sends x,y parameters apart form j_username and j_password. I looked everywhere but could not find where those things were being generated. Have you ever seen such parameters if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` and `y` parameters are sent when the submit is [`<input type="image">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#image-button-state-%28type=image%29). They represent coordinates of the pixel which was clicked. These are completely irrelevant to Spring Security.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I wonder what is the need for that though.